# Is it possible to find out, via the GitHub API, if an issue has been closed via a pull request

Tags: github-api, github-actions

I'm using [github-script](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/github-script) for GitHub actions, which allows you to easily access GitHub API. I'm trying to check if an issue has *not* been closed by clicking on the "close button", that is, via a commit or via merging a pull request that includes a closing commit (or closes in the PR body). However, there does not seem an easy way to do that. This is the event information the GitHub API returns:
[image]

- If the issue has been closed from a commit, it adds the commit_id
- If the issue has been closed from GitHub app (this does not include the web, apparently), `performed_via_github_app` is set to non-null.

However, there does not seem to be a special way to signal an issue has been closed by a pull request, apparently. Or is it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's possible to check whether a specific issue was closed by pull request, commit or button/API using the [GraphQL API](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/graphql) with [`timelineItems`](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/graphql/reference/unions#issuetimelineitems) and filtering on event with state `CLOSED_EVENT` :

```graphql
{
  repository(name: "material-ui", owner: "mui-org") {
    issue(number: 19641) {
      timelineItems(itemTypes: CLOSED_EVENT, last: 1) {
        nodes {
          ... on ClosedEvent {
            createdAt
            closer {
               __typename
              ... on PullRequest {
                baseRefName
                baseRepository {
                  nameWithOwner
                }
                headRefName
                headRepository {
                  nameWithOwner
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[Try it in the explorer](https://developer.github.com/v4/explorer/?query=%7B%0A%20%20repository%28name%3A%20%22material-ui%22%2C%20owner%3A%20%22mui-org%22%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20issue%28number%3A%2019641%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20timelineItems%28itemTypes%3A%20CLOSED_EVENT%2C%20last%3A%201%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20nodes%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20...%20on%20ClosedEvent%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20createdAt%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20closer%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20__typename%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20...%20on%20PullRequest%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20baseRefName%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20baseRepository%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20nameWithOwner%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20headRefName%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20headRepository%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20nameWithOwner%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A)

The `closer` field contains the source of the closing (check `__typename` value) :

- [via pull request](https://github.blog/2013-05-14-closing-issues-via-pull-requests/): `PullRequest`
- [via commit messages](https://github.blog/2013-01-22-closing-issues-via-commit-messages/): `Commit`
- or via the closed button or Github API : `null`

The following requests are example for the 3 types of closing

### Closing via pull request

[This pull request](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/pull/21107) closed [this issue](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/19641)

```graphql
{
  repository(name: "material-ui", owner: "mui-org") {
    issue(number: 19641) {
      timelineItems(itemTypes: CLOSED_EVENT, last: 1) {
        nodes {
          ... on ClosedEvent {
            createdAt
            closer {
              __typename
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Output

```json
{
  "data": {
    "repository": {
      "issue": {
        "timelineItems": {
          "nodes": [
            {
              "createdAt": "2020-05-20T09:06:11Z",
              "closer": {
                "__typename": "PullRequest"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

### Closing via commit message

[This commit](https://github.com/rubinius/rubinius/commit/ac420247b365191e1abe62cd8c6ea5847eb417b6) closed [this issue](https://github.com/rubinius/rubinius/issues/1536)

```graphql
{
  repository(name: "rubinius", owner: "rubinius") {
    issue(number: 1536) {
      timelineItems(itemTypes: CLOSED_EVENT, last: 1) {
        nodes {
          ... on ClosedEvent {
            createdAt
            closer {
              __typename
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Output

```json
{
  "data": {
    "repository": {
      "issue": {
        "timelineItems": {
          "nodes": [
            {
              "createdAt": "2012-01-30T22:33:11Z",
              "closer": {
                "__typename": "Commit"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

### Closing via button or Github API

[This issue](https://github.com/rubinius/rubinius/issues/3830) was closed via the close button :

```graphql
{
  repository(name: "rubinius", owner: "rubinius") {
    issue(number: 3830) {
      timelineItems(itemTypes: CLOSED_EVENT, last: 1) {
        nodes {
          ... on ClosedEvent {
            createdAt
            closer {
              __typename
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Output

```json
{
  "data": {
    "repository": {
      "issue": {
        "timelineItems": {
          "nodes": [
            {
              "createdAt": "2020-02-02T22:31:05Z",
              "closer": null
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Github app uses Github API to make call to close an issue, `performed_via_github_app` is set non `null` if you **open** an issue from an api call generated via a Github app. But `performed_via_github_app` doesn't specify by which mean the issue was closed :

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Well, short answer is no, there's no way to do this and the GitHub API does not reveal either the PR it's been closed from or the fact that it's been closed from a PR as opposed to a commit.
So we'll have to settle for second-best. Often the issue is `connected` to the PR in the previous event. Unless it's an open PR and you've already merged a commit that mentions the issue, you'll have a `connected` and `closed` event the one after the other. So you can use this (or similar) to check for PRs:

```js
issues.forEach( async function( issue ) {
    if ( ! issue.pull_request ) {
          const events = await github.issues.listEvents( { owner: user,
                                                           repo: repo,
                                                           issue_number: issue.number } )
         if ( !events.data ) {
             core.setFailed( "❌ Problema recuperando datos de " + issue.number );
          } else {
             var closing_event
             for (let i = 0; i < events.data.length; i ++ ) {
                  if ( events.data[i].event == 'closed' ) {
                      closing_event = i
                  }
             }
             if ( ! events.data[closing_event].commit_id ) {
                 if ( events.data[closing_event-1].event != 'connected' )   {
                    core.setFailed( "❌ El issue " + issue.number + " no se cerró con un commit o PR");
                 }
             }
         }
     }
                })
```

In this case, it fails if the issue has not been closed either by a commit (in which case the event that closes will have the commit id) or by a PR (in which case *the previous event in the issue* will have been of type `connected`)