# GITHUB API who is the issue solver?

Tags: github, github-api

I'm Working on a GitHub API project, I want to analyze issues of a project, such as who caused how many issues, how often someone causes an issue, etc.

I successfully extracted all the issues of a project using the GitHub API. My question is this:

How can I found the person who solved a specific issue? The person who closes the issue is the person who solved that issue??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same [GitHub API for getting an issue](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/rest/reference/issues#get-an-issue) gives you the sate of the issue anbd who closed it, but... not if it is "resolved".

You would need to use the [GraphQL API](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/graphql) in order to [check if an issue is closed by a resolved (ie merged) PR (Pull Request)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64285944/6309)

Comment: So, can we assume that the person who closed the issue, is the one who solved it?

Comment: @tosicann Yes, even though the "resolution" might simply means "closed/won't fix".

Comment: Sorry, I don't really get what does "resolution" means?

Comment: @tos It means, the issue is closed, either because a pull request fixes it, or because it is considered as no longer fixable.